# How to setup TPM in Dell Edge Gateway 3003 with Ubuntu Core 16?

Tags: apt, dell, ubuntu-core, gnupg, tpm

Currently I am try to configure TPM in Dell Edge Gateway 3003 with Ubuntu Core 16. I have facing some problem gpg key Id generating time.

I try to generate key ID for using  this command: `gpg  --no-use-agent --gen-key`. that time I got the the error entropy number generator:

[image: Not Enough Entropy]

I read different article and blog they can suggest trying `sudo apt-get install rng-tools`  or  `sudo apt-get install -y haveged`   but Ubuntu-core does not support `apt-get`.

How can I solve this error show in image?